# grep search on subdirectories

Tags: grep, find, xargs, text-search

I'm trying to search for a text in a directory among all files. Its expected to access the subfolders too. There are folder & files with whitespace characters in their name. I'm using the following command to search.

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -rls 'my text'
```

This doesn't access the folder and files with white space characters. Any suggestion on what to change on the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should handle files with whitespace just fine I think (though not newlines) but you can use `find -print0` and `xargs -0` to be safer.

That being said your current use of the `-r` argument to `grep` is pointless since it will only ever be given directories to operate on. And additionally your use of `find` here is pointless since `grep -r` does what you want here directly.

Just use `grep -rls 'my text' .`.

Comment: Is there a way I can find the files for matching text instead of the exact text?

Comment: Hm? The files that have a match in them is what `-l` does (instead of reporting the lines that matched).

Answer (score 0):

Any version of `grep` that I personally layed hands on supports the `-r` switch, recursive.

Just hand it the top directory and grep will do its thing:

```
grep -r myregex /home/marcus/bunchoffilesindirectories
```

Comment: The OP is using that flag even.

Comment: @EtanReisner: I know! I just don't think that was clear to OP.